# Next.js 13 App Directory route grouping throwing "Non matching path () provided for /(public)"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to create a different layout for each route groups, there's 3 layouts: auth, dashboard, and public. But when I group the routes, the error "Non matching path () provided for /(public)" occured. Here's my folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

Is there something wrong with the structure? Or is there something i missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NextJs version 13.4.12 with Turbopack, I'm getting that error. Simply, use webpack again by removing "dev": "next dev ---turbo" from the package.json script and replace it with "dev": "next dev." At least for now, in beta, it may have some errors.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding and according to the documents, the folder `(public )` is only for grouping and won't be consider a path, in order to make the route accessible you need to put the `page.js` inside another folder eg: `(public)/public/page.js` This will make it accessible by `/public` route.